# Implications of including GPL software in a distribution?

Tags: gcc, distributions, licenses, gpl

It's well known that the FreeBSD project is actively trying to route out all traces of GPL'ed software in favor of more permissive-licensed software replacements.[1]

Their reasons are ambitious, although sound.

I'm currently working on a pet-project of which one component is an embedded Linux distribution. I need a C compiler to be present on the system, mainly `gcc`.

I'm aware other components of this setup are GPL'ed, mainly the Kernel, however it is still on GPLv2 (and will remain), while current versions of GCC are now on GPLv3.

Although this is a pet project, there is a likelihood it may be sold in a commercial environment, and I would like to avoid any licensing issues.

GCC's source is already available for any possible customers, but would I have to give my customers access to the entire distribution's code (all already available), my custom build scripts, and the actual product code running on-top of the platform (Java and C)?

~~~~

What are the implications of including GPL'ed software in a project which will ultimately be sold commercially?

~~~~

[1] [Why is FreeBSD deprecating GCC in favor of Clang/LLVM?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49906/why-is-freebsd-deprecating-gcc-in-favor-of-clang-llvm#answer-49970)

Comment: Take a look at this doc: https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/articles/bsdl-gpl/article.html

Comment: The FSF site covers a lot of what you are asking. You *have* checked it out, right? E.g. http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html