# Is it ok to use gcc to compile userspace binaries on FreeBSD 10?

Tags: compiling, freebsd, gcc, licenses, clang

I know that recently FreeBSD 10 dumped `gcc` in favour of clang due to licensing reasons ([Ref](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49906/why-is-freebsd-deprecating-gcc-in-favor-of-clang-llvm/49970)).

I wanted to understand if this restriction to use clang is limited only to kernel compilation.

Can I use gcc compiled Python on FreeBSD 10?

(I read some of the articles related to clang, gcc and FreeBSD 10. But could not conclude on above question.)

Answer (score 4):

From the article you are refering to (at the very bottom):

> nothing prevents a user from installing and using a modern GCC on
>   their FreeBSD box themselves.

So it is perfectly valid (legally speaking), for a specific user, to install a modern gcc on a FreeBSD 10.x then use it to compile and install Python.

First install a modern gcc from the "*ports*" (ie: `/usr/ports/lang/gcc48`).

Then, to force the use of gcc with the "*ports*", edit your `/etc/make.conf` and add:

```
.if !empty(.CURDIR:M/usr/ports/*) && exists(/usr/local/bin/gcc48)
CC=gcc48
CXX=g++48
CPP=cpp48
.endif
```

A bit more [here (doma's blog)](http://lajosd.blogspot.fr/2014/09/using-gcc48-to-build-ports-on-freebsd.html) - though, the `libmap.conf` part might not be required for a simple Python compiling.